# How to package shared library in deb packages

Tags: deb, packaging, shared-library

My application uses some shared libraries, which i need to package with the binary, and as per
[Debian Policy Rules](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-sharedlibs.html)

> It is recommended that supporting files and run-time support programs that do not need to be invoked manually by users, but are nevertheless required for the package to function, be placed (if they are binary) in a subdirectory of `/usr/lib`, preferably under `/usr/lib/package-name`.

So, I put my shared library e.g. `libabc.so` in `/usr/lib/myapp/` directory. After creating the debian package the binary fails to load as `/usr/lib/myapp/` is not searched by the loader to load the directory. They don't recommend using **`RPATH`** in the binary.

So what changes should i make in the Debian package, in the **`postinst`** file or anything else to make it work.

Comment: What's the nature of the binary that fails to load your shared library? Where is it installed? Is it using the system's dynamic linker, or `dlopen`?

Comment: @RobieBasak It is a Qt application, which uses libmetalink.so library. The binary is installed in /usr/bin/ . And i don't know what dlopen or dynamic linker is.

Answer (score 0):

No, your shared library should be installed:

- to `/usr/lib` directly
- or to `/usr/lib/<package-name>` with a shortcut in `/usr/lib`

The manual means:

- by `supporting files` like plugins and modules (in binary form) that your program would scan them by itself. They could be shared libs `.so` or any other format, even custom formats.
- by `run-time support programs` the executable programs that are used by your program, but are not useful for the user to run them directly, so that note suggests to avoid installing them to `/usr/bin`

The support files in text format (not generated-binary at least) are more convenient to be installed in `/usr/share/<package-name>`

I would recommend to you, making quick look on examples from other packages.

```
tree /usr/lib/libreoffice/
tree /usr/lib/gimp/
```